# Execute different job for environment rollback in GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm setting up a new pipeline for a project with various development stages. I wanted to use GitLab's ["Environments and Deployments"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/environments/) feature to represent those. Due to the nature of the deployments, I need to execute some extra actions on rollback, so I'd like to execute a different job when rolling back (similar to `on_stop` behavior.)

As far as I can see, there is no way to do this, though:

- It will say so in the UI, but technically, this is just another run of the same job that ran before it.
- There is also no indication in the environment variables at job runtime.
- The API has also proven unhelpful, as it doesn't distinguish *why* a job has been triggered, rather just listing all of them and treating them like "forward deployments" (i.e. rollouts.)

Am I missing something?

I would be really thankful for any suggestion pointing me into the right direction.